# Using JavaMailSenderImpl from multiple threads and having reconnection mechanism?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, email

We are using [JavaMailSenderImpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html) to send thousands of emails per day. Previously, we instantiated JavaMailSenderImpl with a private method to send each email rather than using it as a bean. Recently, I moved it to be used as a bean, and we will have several since we have multiple mail hosts.

My question is how to properly check for Session/Transport and reconnect before sending a batch of emails and what the optimal approach would be if JavaMailSenderImpl session got disconnected in the middle of batch processing, given that multiple threads will be used.

Here is the code:

```java
@Bean("myMailSender")
public JavaMailSender myMailSender(){
   JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
   javaMailSender.setHost(host);
   javaMailSender.setPort(port);
   javaMailSender.setUsername(sername);
   javaMailSender.setPassword(password);
   return javaMailSender;
}

ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new NamedThreadFactory("ParallelEmail-"));

try {
   Session session = mailSender.getSession();
   if (session.getTransport() == null || !session.getTransport().isConnected()) {
       Transport t = null;
       try {
           t = session.getTransport();
           t.connect(mailSender.getHost(), mailSender.getPort(), mailSender.getUsername(), mailSender.getPassword());
       } catch (MessagingException e){
           log.error("There was an error when re-connecting to mailhost " + mailSender.getHost());
       }
   }
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e1){
   log.error("There was an error when fetching an existing session for mailhost " + mailSender.getHost());
}

for (Email msg: getFromDb()) {
   executorService.execute(
           () -> {
               MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = getMsgPrep(msg);
               try{
                   mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
               } catch (MailException exception){
                   log.error(exception.getMessage());
                   //Reattempt for second time?
                   //I don’t want all threads to start reconnecting, just the first one which gets to this line.
               }
           }
   );
}
```

Comment: If you are doing `mailSender.getSession` you are doing it wrong. Use `MailSender.send`. You are already connected to the host, no need to reconnect again. What you are hacking into your code is already being done by the mailsender.send method. I would suggest using the `send` method that allows multiple `MimeMessagePreparator` instances, which handles all this for you.

Comment: I did exactly like that. If you want, place this comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you M. Deinum for looking into this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing `mailSender.getSession` you are doing it wrong. The whole idea of the `JavaMailSender` is to abstract away the handling of the mail session and the whole Java Mail API.

Use `MailSender.send` as you are already connected to the host, no need to reconnect again. What you are hacking into your code is already being done by the `mailsender.send` method.

I would suggest using the send [method that allows multiple](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html#send(org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator...)) `MimeMessagePreparator` instances, which handles all this for you.